# How to get video over USB-C working with external monitor?

Tags: usb, live-usb, monitor

I have a Lenovo ThinkVision monitor with a built-in USB dock. When I connect it via USB-C to my HP laptop, I can use the keyboard and mouse connected to the dock, but no video is  displayed. Any help is appreciated!

When I plug in the USB-C cable, [here's what is appended](https://pastebin.com/rxVFA985) to kern.log. My current kernel version is 5.11.0-31-generic, and I'm using Ubuntu 21.04. I was also able to use the USB-C connection to send video to the monitor from my 2020 Macbook Air.

Comment: Does your "HP laptop" has video over USB-C? If not mentioned/specified by the manufacturer then it doesn't have it, not all USB-C are made equal.

Comment: Maybe this is a late response, but you may need to install the [DisplayLink drivers](https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu).